# How do I get a wrapper div's background-color to expand with the height

Tags: css, html

I have a div that wraps a number of actions a user can take. This div is like an actionBar that you'd see at the top of a table. It has 3 elements: 1) a button group, 2) a group of selects and 3) pagination controls.

I have the first two elements floating left and the last one floating right. This works great and everything lines up great when the browser window is wide enough to fit everything. However, when the screen resolution is smaller or the user makes the browser too narrow, the elements wrap. The wrapping I like, but the div does not expand its height (and associated background color) to fit the wrapped elements.

How do I make the div expand its height to fit these wrapped elements.

See the problem in action at http://jsfiddle.net/mraible/bJQCL/.

Comment: Be sure to add `background-image: linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);` to `.wrapper` for forward-compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the fixed height on the wrapper and add `overflow:auto` to it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bJQCL/3/)**.

Comment: this was correct, I don't know why anyone would give you -1, I just voted this up :)

Comment: It should be noted this can cause a scrollbar to appear if any of the [interior content is wider than 100%](http://jsfiddle.net/bJQCL/4/).

Comment: @bfrohs - by removing the height rule this stops the scrollbar from appearing and allows the div to expand naturally.

Comment: @j08691, for `width`, not `height` (I provided a link to a jsFiddle showing it happen with *your* code).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove wrapper div fixed height & add overflow:hidden or auto to that div.

Comment: OOps! sorry! Ya i mean height.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the static height on `.wrapper`. Then, you have two options:

1. Use `overflow:auto` to force `.wrapper` to contain its contents ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bJQCL/7/)):

   ```css
   .wrapper {
       background-color: #CBE6A5;
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       background-image: linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       overflow:auto;
   }
   ```

   ***Note:** This can cause an unwanted scrollbar with content wider than 100% ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bJQCL/8/)).*
2. Use `:after` to force `.wrapper` to contain its contents ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bJQCL/6/)):

   ```css
   .wrapper {
       background-color: #CBE6A5;
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       background-image: linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
   }
   .wrapper:after {
       display:block;
       content:".";
       font-size:0;
       height:0;
       color:transparent;
       clear:left;
   }
   ```

   ***Note:** This does not work in IE7 and below.*
3. Add a "clear" `div` to the end of `.wrapper` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bJQCL/9/)):

   ```
   <div class="clear"></div>
   ```

   ```css
   .wrapper {
       background-color: #CBE6A5;
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
       background-image: linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
   }
   .clear {
       clear:left;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FghLm/)

Simply add height:auto and an overflow of auto.

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #CBE6A5;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CBE6A5, #E2F1CD);
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: The jsFiddle link is the same as Matt's and `height:auto;` is not necessary.